# lazy list computed using mutable state?

Tags: haskell, state, lazy-evaluation, mutable

I'd like to figure out in general how to use mutable state in the computation of lazy lists.

For instance, here is a naive Sieve of Eratosthenes implemented using a mutable array ([source](http://mukeshiiitm.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/project-euler-357/)):

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

prime :: Int -> UArray Int Bool
prime n = runSTUArray $ do
    arr <- newArray ( 2 , n ) True :: ST s ( STUArray s Int Bool )
    forM_ ( takeWhile ( \x -> x*x <= n ) [ 2 .. n ] ) $ \i -> do
        ai <- readArray arr i
        when ( ai  ) $ forM_ [ i^2 , i^2 + i .. n ] $ \j -> do
            writeArray arr j False
            -- yield i ???
```

`prime n` returns an array of booleans which denote which numbers are prime.

Is there a way to use this approach to create a lazy-list of those primes? It would be like adding a `yield i` right after the `writeArray` statement.

Comment: You could also use the State Monad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The smallest modification of your program to achieve lazyness is probably to switch to the *lazy* ST monad (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST-Lazy.html), where this code would work:

```
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

prime :: Int -> [Int]
prime n = catMaybes $ runST $ do
    arr <- strictToLazyST $ newArray ( 2 , n ) True :: ST s ( STUArray s Int Bool )
    forM ( takeWhile ( \x -> x <= n ) [ 2 .. n ] ) $ \i -> do
        if i == 83 then error "Reached 83" else return ()
        ai <- strictToLazyST $ readArray arr i
        if ai
          then do
            strictToLazyST $ forM_ [ i^2 , i^2 + i .. n ] $
                 \j -> writeArray arr j False
            return (Just i)
          else return Nothing
```

The error call is just to demonstrate the true lazy nature of the result:

```
*Main> prime 10000
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79*** Exception: Reached 83
```

If you want to avoid the intermediate list of `Maybes`, you can, for example, use this code:

```
import Control.Monad.ST.Lazy
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Data.Functor

prime :: Int -> [Int]
prime n = runST $ do
    arr <- strictToLazyST $ newArray ( 2 , n ) True :: ST s ( STUArray s Int Bool )
    let primesFrom i | i > n = return []
                     | otherwise = do
            ai <- strictToLazyST $ readArray arr i
            if ai then do
                strictToLazyST $ forM_ [ i^2 , i^2 + i .. n ] $
                   \j -> writeArray arr j False
                (i:) <$> primesFrom (i + 1)
              else primesFrom (i + 1)
    primesFrom 2
```

Comment: thanks! seems to do what I need, except that for some reason the first program seems to stop at sqrt n, e.g. `prime 10` returns `[2,3]`

Comment: the second example works perfectly if the first guard clause for `primesFrom i` is changed to `| i > n = return []`

Comment: In the first one, the `takeWhile` needs an `x^2`.

Comment: You may also want to move the  `strictToLazyST` calls outside the `forM_`. I don't know if it would affect efficiency, but it certainly should make it clearer.

Comment: FYI, I'm going to try using this technique to implement an O'Neill sieve using an array-based priority queue—profiling suggests the functional queue is killing performance.

Comment: Now that the concurrency bug with lazy ST is (apparently) squashed, it definitely pays a lot to pull `strictToLazy` out of the loop whenever it doesn't break laziness (when running with the threaded RTS). I edited accordingly, hopefully without breaking anything.