# List Iterator using ContT

Tags: haskell, iterator, continuations

I have a simple list that I would like to iterate over "yield"ing between each element and printing that element to the output. I am trying to use the ContT monad to do this but running into issues. Here's what I have so far:

```
data K a = Nil | K (a,() -> K a)
listIterator :: (Monad m) => [r] -> m (K r)
listIterator [] = return Nil
listIterator (x:xs) = return (ContT (\k -> K (x,k))) >> listIterator xs

runIterator :: IO ()
runIterator = do
  a <- listIterator ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
  let loop Nil = liftIO $ print "nil"
      loop (K (curr,newI)) =
          do
        liftIO $ print curr
        loop (newI ())
  loop a
```

The expected output is:

```
1
2
3
nil
```

What I get is:

```
nil
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since haskell is lazy you already have the continuation benefits with the simple list type (`[]`), but I guess you do this to learn. :)

Comment: Is this somehow related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596151/lazy-list-computed-using-mutable-state?

Comment: Note that in Haskell, `() -> a` is the same thing as just `a`, due to laziness and purity. The only reason to use the former is if you are using a higher-order function that *requires* a function rather than a plain value.

Comment: Also note that the canonical way to write code like this would be `mapM_ print [1, 2, 3] >> putStrLn "nil"`.

Answer (score 4):

```
listIterator (x:xs) = return (ContT (\k -> K (x,k))) >> listIterator xs
```

does not do what you expect, equational reasoning

```
listIterator (x:xs) 
= return (ContT (\k -> K (x,k))) >> listIterator xs
= (return (ContT (\k -> K (x,k)))) >>= \_ -> listIterator xs
= (\_ -> listIterator xs) (ContT (\k -> K (x,k)))
= listIterator xs
```

---

I'm not sure exactly why you want to use an iterator.  Haskell is already lazy, so iteration patterns like this are mostly used only when you have resource management issues that need to interact well with a demand driven usage pattern.  And, you don't need the continuation monad at all:

Instead of writing the `K` constructor to take a tuple it is more idiomatic to

```
data K a = Nil | K a (() -> K a)
```

intuitively, the type for the `listIterator` does not use its monadic structure: it just constructs a value, so

```
listIterator ::[r] -> K r
listIterator [] = Nil
listIterator (x:xs) = K x (\_ -> listIterator xs)
```

now life is trivial

```
runIterator :: IO ()
runIterator = do
 let a = listIterator ([1,2,3] :: [Int])
     loop Nil = liftIO $ print "nil"
     loop (K curr newI) =
         do
       liftIO $ print curr
       loop (newI ())
 loop a
```

which would probably be best to write without the use of do notation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Hopefully you see what I'm trying to do, can you offer any direction?

Comment: As a note for future visitors: Since as noted Haskell has non-strict semantics, `() -> K a` is actually equivalent to `K a`, and so `K a (K a)` is in fact enough.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you were looking for, but if you are interested in this style of programming, you should look into `pipes` and similar libraries. (`conduit` is the rising star in the "real world", but pipes provides a simpler tool for teaching which is why I use it here.)

```
$ cabal update && cabal install pipes
```

Pipes are like iterators, except they come in three flavors: those that can acquire input (Consumers), those that produce output (Producers), and those that do both (Pipes). If you connect pipes such that the input and output ends are all satisfied, then it is called a "Pipeline", and it is a self-contained unit that can be run without any additional input.

Pipe provides a monad instance for convenience in creating pipes. The `>+>` operator connects two pipes together.

```
import Control.Pipe
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

-- annoyingly, Pipe does not provide a MonadIO instance
instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (Pipe a b m) where
  liftIO = lift . liftIO

listIterator :: Monad m => [a] -> Producer (Maybe a) m ()
listIterator (x:xs) = yield (Just x) >> listIterator xs
listIterator []     = yield Nothing

printer :: (MonadIO m, Show a) => Consumer (Maybe a) m ()
printer = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Just x -> liftIO (print x) >> printer
    Nothing -> liftIO (putStrLn "nil")

main = runPipe $ listIterator [1, 2, 3] >+> printer
```

The [source for Control.Pipe](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/2.1.0/doc/html/src/Control-Pipe.html) is delightfully simple, especially if you have been reading Gabriel's recent blog posts about Free monads, particularly [Why free monads matter](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) and [Purify code using free monads](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html).